# Can Eudora be set to be the default mail client on OS X?

Tags: mail.app

I was using Eudora for email on my Mac.  I just activated the Apple Mail application and now I can no longer receive new messages in Eudora.  I can send, but not receive.  I get an error message alluding to password error.  I can read the new messages in Apple Mail, but prefer Eudora.  Can I uninstall Apple Mail?

Comment: Could you edit your question to specify Eudora and OS X versions and perhaps a screen shot of the eudora error (or at least a precise wording) of what it says is the problem.

Comment: In addition the title/goal (get rid of Apple Mail) doesn't directly match the problem (wrong password/connection problem) encountered. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Open up Mail.app, and visit the preferences (Menu Bar>Mail>Preferences).

Change the default mail client in the drop-down menu under "General" to Eudora.

[image]

If you really wanted, you could just drag Mail.app from your Applications folder to the Trash at that point, but I would just leave it and ignore it.